# Building Vulkan Chopper demo on ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, compiling, opengl, 16.04, vulkan

How to build nvidia vulkan chopper demo on ubuntu (16.04)?

https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_vk_chopper

After being able to build, I get segfault.

Can someone make instruction how to build? (i don't find a binary yet)

Comment: This does not seem like an Ubuntu specific problem. Also Vulkan is not fully supported yet.

Comment: Also you're using 16.04, a development branch release. I'm going to flag your question since it's off-topic here.

Comment: People suceeded building this demo on SteamOS (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YX_7XZ9hhMY). Also 16.04 will soon be released and many people will try something similar. 16.04 only ubuntu you can use Vulkan on. I disagree it's "off-topic"

Comment: Yes, it **is** off-topic. Read Ask Ubuntu's rules: only current releases are considered valid here. End of life releases do not have support and so do in-development ones.

Comment: @EduardoCola if the question would be for current ubuntu release (pr not a apecific release), would it make more sense?